# Reactjs router transition is messed up

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm trying to implement react's router transition.

There's a transition, but it's messed up - the entering route appears, fades out then appears again. But not even for all routes! Additionally, there's no exit transition.

What I want is a simple smooth fade between each route. How can I do so?

I have the following already set up:

```
const App = ({location}) => {

    return (
        <section className="main__wrapper">
            <ScrollToTop/>
            <Header/>
            <TransitionGroup>
                <CSSTransition
                    key={location.key}
                    timeout={{enter: 1000, exit: 1000}}
                    classNames={'fade'}>
                    <Switch>
                        <Route path="/" exact>
                            <Home/>
                            <Projects/>
                        </Route>
                        <Route path="/project/:name" exact>
                            <Project/>
                        </Route>
                        <Route path="/about" exact>
                            <About/>
                        </Route>
                    </Switch>
                </CSSTransition>
            </TransitionGroup>
        </section>

    );
};

export default withRouter(App);
```

```
.fade-enter {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 1000ms;
}

.fade-exit {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 1000ms;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `react-router-transition` which provides easy way to add transitions to routes

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router-transition

Here is sample demo website

http://maisano.github.io/react-router-transition/getting-started